# How to create menu in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, menu

I have just created a MVC 4 project and selected "Basic" Template in VS2012. I have created a "HomeController" and two methods inside it: "Index" and "Details". I have generated a view for both the methods: "Index.cshtml" and "Details.cshtml". My question is how to create a basic menu for them in "_Layout.cshtml"?

Comment: see the the existing menus and add your ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting a "menu" that consists of populating the header bar with links to the different views  , you can add buttons. Although I am confused as to why these were not generated with the project creation. Here is one of the default bootstrap layout headers. They use @Html.ActionLink.

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default MVC template should already have a basic menu with Home, About, Contact menu options.  You can just add to that.